# Algorithm for multiple extended string matching

Tags: algorithms, search

I need to implement an algorithm for multiple extended string matching in text. Algorithms to match regular expression would be perhaps too slow.

**Extended** means the presence of wildcards (any number of characters instead of a star), for example:

```
abc*def //matches abcdef, abcpppppdef etc.
```

**Multiple** means that the search is going on simultaneously for multiple string patterns (not a separate search for each pattern), for example:

```
abc*def
abc
whatever
some*string
```

**QUESTION:**

What is the fast algorithm that can do multiple extended string matching?

Preferably, optimized for SIMD instructions and multicore implementation. Open source implementation (C/C++/Python) would be great as well. I'm interested in 10 Gbps+ performance on a single core of a modern CPU.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest that we close this question on this site. It is a duplicate, cross-posted on Cross Validated and migrated to StackOverflow, where it already has an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28962097/2872891. Anyone, wanting to add their answer, can do so on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend regexp pattern matching. I know that usual implementations are slow but you have to study Thompson's construction algorithm for nondeterministic automaton. See the wikipedia dedicated [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm). However here the wikipedia fails to present this treasure properly. I would strongly recommend to study carefuly this blog article: [Regular expressions can be simple and fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). For implementations you have pointers in the given article (for example awk and grep uses this implementation).

Answer (score 2):

Do you change the patterns often? If not, then you can use Aho-Corasick method, whose idea is, first, to build a finite automaton based on your patterns and, then, to make a single pass over the text with this automaton to find matches (if the automaton visits a "matching" state, then there is a match). The complexity of the automata building should be linear in the length of the patterns (# of patters * max pattern length), and the matching phase should be linear in the size of the text you search in.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Can you recommend any good Aho-Corasick implementation/flavor that can handle extended matching features (* and ? ) and preferably SIMD instructions? Naive implementations I tried were quite slow and didn't have extended matching features.

Comment: Patterns are to be changed moderately often, so I could recompile the automaton once it happens.